# Getting app run id for a Spark job

Tags: apache-spark

I'd like, from where I run a Spark job, to get the unique id of that job.

Via the Spark master node website, I can see that id. It's something like:

```
ID: app-20140429125304-0452
```

Is there any way to get this, when creating a running a job? Maybe via the SparkContext?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

yes, exactly as you said:

```
sc.applicationId
res0: String = app-20150224184813-11531
```

(This is spark 1.2)

See API doc at

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext

Comment: pyspark 1.3 does not have `sc.applicationId`

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I don't think the version of Spark I was on had this, on the context - very glad they've added it!

Comment: But Java version is lacking this one?

Answer (score 5):

For those using pyspark, see this nearly identical question: [How to extract application ID from the PySpark context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983226/how-to-extract-application-id-from-the-pyspark-context)

The answer from @vvladymyrov worked for me running pyspark in yarn-client mode.

```
>>> sc._jsc.sc().applicationId()
u'application_1433865536131_34483'
```

Answer (score 5):

With the introduction of the `spark: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession` from Spark 2.0+ on use

```
scala> spark.sparkContext.applicationId
res1: String = app-20170228091742-0025
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which language you are using.

**Scala**

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext

```
sc.applicationId
```

**Java**

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html

```
sparkContext.sc().applicationId();
```

**Python**

http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext

```
sc.applicationId
```

It can also depend on Spark version.