# How to extract application ID from the PySpark context

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, pyspark

A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23378407/850781) recommends `sc.applicationId`, but it is *not* present in `PySpark`, only in `scala`.

So, how do I figure out the application id (for `yarn`) of my PySpark process?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext . Lookup for `id()`

Comment: @ccheneson: there are 3 matches, all for RDD.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use Java SparkContext object through the Py4J RPC gateway:

```
>>> sc._jsc.sc().applicationId()
u'application_1433865536131_34483'
```

Please note that `sc._jsc` is internal variable and not the part of public API - so there is (rather small) chance that it may be changed in the future.

I'll submit pull request to add public API call for this.

Comment: please add a link to your pull request here so that we can vote for it.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8528 https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/6936

Comment: Spark team accepted by PR - so sc.applicationID property will be available in Spark 1.5.0 release

Answer (score 6):

In Spark 1.6 (probably 1.5 according to @wladymyrov in comment on the other answer)

```
In [1]: sc.applicationId
Out[1]: u'local-1455827907865'
```

Comment: I confirm that `sc.applicationId` is available in Spark 1.5.2.

Answer (score 5):

**For PySpark 2.0.0+**

```
spark_session = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

app_id = spark_session._sc.applicationId
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like its [available in 3.0.1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.applicationId) at least:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName('Overriding defaults app name') \
    .getOrCreate()
print(f'--- {spark.sparkContext.applicationId} ---')
```

Results in:

```
--- application_1610550667906_166057 ---
```