# how to get Application ID from Submission ID or Driver ID programmatically

Tags: apache-spark

I am submitting a Spark Job in cluster deploy-mode. i am getting Submission ID in my code. In order to use Spark rest Api we need applicationId. So how can we get Application Id via Submission ID programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract application ID from the PySpark context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983226/how-to-extract-application-id-from-the-pyspark-context)

Comment: How do you get Submission ID inside the program. I have app id in the program and need Submission ID inside it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question there is assumed that there is known that the certificate ID can be obtained with the function:

```
scala> spark.sparkContext.applicationId
```

If you want to get it is a little different. Over the rest API it is possible to send commands. For example like in the following useful tutorial about the Apache REST API: http://arturmkrtchyan.com/apache-spark-hidden-rest-api
Another solution is to program it yourself. You can send a Spark submit in the following style:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi  \
--master spark://my-cluster:7077 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
/path/to/examples.jar 1000
```

Here in the background of the terminal you should see the log file being produced. In the log file there is the Application ID (App_ID). The `$SPARK_HOME` is here the environment variable leading to the folder where spark is located.

With for example **Python** it is possible to obtain the App_ID in the code described below. First we create a list to send the command with Python its `subprocess` module. The subprocess module has the possibility to make a PIPE from which you can extract the log information instead of using Spark its standard option to post it to the terminal. Make sure to use `communicate()` after the Popen, to prevent waiting for the OS. Then split it in lines and scrape throught it to find the `App_ID`. The example can be find below:

```
submitSparkList=['$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit','--class','org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi','--master spark://my-cluster:7077','--deploy-mode cluster','/path/to/examples.py','1000']
sparkCommand=subprocess.Popen(submitSparkList,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = sparkCommand.communicate()
stderr=stderr.splitlines() 
for line in stderr:      
     if "Connected to Spark cluster" in  line: #this is the first line from the rest API that contains the ID. Scrape through the logs to find it. 
        app_ID_index=line.find('app-')
        app_ID=line[app_ID_index:] #this gives the app_ID
        print('The app ID is ' + app_ID)
```

Following the Python guide this contains a warning when not using communicate() function:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Warning This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use communicate() to avoid that.

Comment: currently `spark-submit` (2.4.x) returns only the driver id for Spark standalone in cluster deploy mode. To get the app id you have to go client mode (or grep the master logs, if you have the access rights).