# Running a spark job and getting the job id via script

Tags: python, apache-spark

Similar to [Getting app run id for a Spark job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378407/getting-app-run-id-for-a-spark-job), except from the command line or a script.

I am running `spark-submit` automatically from our continuous deployment system, and I need to track the application ID so that I can kill it before running the job again (and various other needs).

Specifically, this is a Python script that executes the job on a YARN cluster, and can read standard output from `spark-submit`, which we need to save the application ID for a later time.

The best plan I can figure so far is to run `spark-submit`, watch standard output and extract the application ID, then detach from the process. This method is not ideal in my opinion.

Preferably, `spark-submit` would (only) print out the application ID, then fork, and so far I don't see any way of doing this apart from modifying Spark itself.

Is there a nicer, more obvious way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a wrapper script that extracts the application ID for you. It's hosted at: https://github.com/gak/spark-submit-app-id-wrapper

Example:

```
# pip install spark-submit-app-id-wrapper

# ssaiw spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --class etc etc > /dev/null
application_1448925599375_0050
```

Now the CI script can run `spark-submit` via `ssaiw` and grab the application id as soon as possible.

Note that it has only been tested with YARN.