# how can i retrieve a unique spark job-id in Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23378407/317027).  But I don't seem to be able to find applicationid on `JavaSparkContext`.

Actually want I need is a unique id that identifies the application.  I could just generate uuid and set it as app-name.  Is there a better way?

Comment: @morfious902002 ctxt.getConf().getAppId() this worked great...would you like to add it as the answer and I'll mark it so...thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :-

```
JavaSC.env().conf().getAppId();
```

or

```
ctxt.getConf().getAppId()
```